# How to log DNS queries from my home network?

Tags: dns, logging

I want to log all DNS lookups from computers on my home wireless network.  What's the best way to do this?

Options I know of:

1. Using OpenDNS and let it log queries for me.  However, in order to then generate reports from their logs, I have to use a javascript-enabled headless browser to log into their `stats` web page and download stats to a script.  This is painful.
2. Run my own DNS server using djbdns or dnsmasq or some caching resolver (that isn't `bind` because that scares me), and have it generate log files.  The problem here is making sure that nameserver stays up and the logs are rolled, etc.
3. Use port-forwarding with logging and run `iptables` on a machine to forward to 8.8.8.8:53 (or whatever) after logging each query.  This has the advantage that I'm forwarding to a robust DNS server rather than running my own, but I don't think what's logged will contain the full DNS query (there appears to be a netfilter hack that does what I want, but I'm reluctant to modify my kernel for this simple project).

Are there other options that I'm overlooking here?

Answer (score 1):

Im sure there is better way to do this, especially if your router supports logging.

However here is a quick and dirty method you can use per machine.

You can use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to see all your DNS queries.  You can run a capture on your interface and then filter for DNS.  Below is a sample DNS capture, filtered for DNS:

[image]

Its interesting, you go to superuser.com and it queries a bunch of other StackExchange sites.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the **NAS boxes**, such as Synology, actually run Linux and have DNS packages available.  An Atom-based or ARM NAS doesn't use much power and you can leave it on all of the time.

Alternatively, a $35 **Raspberry Pi** is more than powerful enough to host a DNS and/or DHCP server.  There are lots of great distros where installing logrotate is trivial.  You could also have it mail you a digest weekly if that's what you want.

Running your own caching DNS is a good idea and can often have a positive benefits such as:

- Lower latency for DNS requests (if the request has been seen lately)
- Allows for DHCP DNS registration
- Run your own internal domain without messing with the hosts file on all of your devices
- Plus even nerdier things I won't get into